# analytical matrix inversion?

Tags: matrices, inverse

I have a square matrix $M$ with matrix elements of the form $M_{jk}=j^k$, is there an analytical expression for the matrix elements of $M^{-1}$? If the result is known, references are much appreciated.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde%27s_Matrix ?

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown thank you!